# std::to_string is not declared compile error in aix

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, aix

I am compiling my code in AIX env.. it givs me error "std::to_string" is not declared 
successfully compiled same code in Windows.

```
define LOG_MSG(message) CLogManager::LogMessage(CLogManager::CurrentDateTime() + " - " + std::string(__FILE__) + "[" + std::to_string(static_cast<_ULonglong>(__LINE__)) + "] : " + std::string(message) + "\n")
```

This is the macro and i am using this as

```
LOG_MSG(" ** BEGIN StorePasswordFromFile()");
```

This macro is for logging purpose

Comment: did you `#include<string>` ?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11?

Comment: Are you using IBM XLC or GCC?

Comment: I am using IBM XLC... included string also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much support the latest `xlC 14.1` (or whatever version you're using) has for `std::to_string()`.

If the support is incomplete, C has a hideous double macro method <sup>(a)</sup> of turning `__LINE__` into a C-string so that you can just use `std::string`, the same as you have for the `__FILE__` and `message` items, and it appears the C++ pre-processor has stayed faithful to its hideous roots :-)

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STR1(x) # x
#define STR2(x) STR1(x)
int main(void) {
    char x[] = __FILE__;
    char y[] = STR2(__LINE__);
    printf("file = %s, line = %s\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
file = qq.c, line = 6
```

showing that the `__LINE__` has been successfully morphed into a C-string value.

You should be able to use a similar method in your macro:

```
#define STR1(x) # x
#define STR2(x) STR1(x)
#define LOG_MSG(message) CLogManager::LogMessage( \
    CLogManager::CurrentDateTime() + " - " + \
    std::string(__FILE__) + "[" + \
    std::string(STR2(__LINE__)) + "] : " + \
    std::string(message) + "\n")

int main() {
    LOG_MSG ("My hovercraft is full of eels");
    return 0;
}
```

Pre-processing that with `g++ -E qq.cpp` gives you:

```
  CLogManager::LogMessage( CLogManager::CurrentDateTime() + " - " + std::string("qq.cpp") + "[" + std::string("10") + "] : " + std::string("My hovercraft is full of eels") + "\n");
```

(showing relevant line only) which seems to match what you want.

As a side note however, since you seem to be okay adding C-strings like `"["` *without* needing to construct strings explicitly, I'm not sure that you *need* the `std::string()` calls at all for those. You still need the C macro hack to turn the integer into a C-string but, once that's been done, you should just be able to use that as-is.

Changing the final macro to:

```
#define LOG_MSG(message) CLogManager::LogMessage( \
    CLogManager::CurrentDateTime() + " - " + \
    __FILE__ + "[" + \
    STR2(__LINE__) + "] : " + \
    message + "\n")
```

will give you:

```
CLogManager::LogMessage( CLogManager::CurrentDateTime() + " - " + "qq.cpp" + "[" + "10" + "] : " + "My hovercraft is full of eels" + "\n");
```

Whether that's a good *idea,* I'll leave to the wider community but it at least gets around your immediate problem. I'd probably place the whole lot inside an `#if/#else/#endif` so that C++11 compilers that know about `std::to_string()` can use the more accepted approach.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're interested in *why* this works, I'll explain below.

The `#` and `##` macro operators actually take precedence over the recursive nature of macro replacement, as per `C11 6.10.3.4 /1`:

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ##
>   processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. The
>   resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent
>   preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.

That means that the code:

```
#define STR(x) # x
STR(__LINE__)
```

will actually result in `"__LINE__"` because the `#` happens first and, once that's happened, the `__LINE__` within the string literal is not subject to further replacement. By doing the two-step process:

```
#define STR1(x) # x
#define STR2(x) STR1(x)
STR2(__LINE__)
```

the first level of replacement turns `STR2(__LINE__)` into `STR1(3)` because `__LINE__` on its own is subject to expansion.

Then the second level turns `STR1(3)`, via `# 3`, into `"3"`.

Perhaps the following may help:

```
#define STR1(x) # x
#define STR2a(x) STRn(x)
#define STR2b(x) STR1(x)

STR1(__LINE__)
STR2a(__LINE__)
STR2b(__LINE__)
```

The output of that, annotated, is:

```
"__LINE__"  - stringise, no further processing of __LINE__ inside literal.
STRn(6)     - shows first stage of replacement, line number replacement.
"7"         - shows full process.
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your solution it worked for me.. but can you please tell me how it workes?

Comment: @user2991556: see the addendum to the answer.